# Why does c99 const arg allow changing sub values without warnings?

Tags: c, c99

I haven't done C or C++ in well over a decade, and I'm working on a small project to get myself comfortable with it again, and trying to figure out good vs bad habits where I can.  One thing I came across was `const` arguments, which are not only supposed to be a signal to consumers that values won't change.  I'm a big fan of immutability signals so I thought this would be great.

Until I started playing with it and wrote up the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
    int value;
};

struct B {
    struct A* a;
};

void DoStuff(const struct B* b) {
    b->a->value = 5;
}

int main() {
    struct B* b = malloc(sizeof(struct B));
    b->a = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
    DoStuff(b);

    printf("Value: %i\n", b->a->value);
}
```

Much to my surprise when I compiled via `gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 test.c -o test.exe` I got no warnings, errors, or anything and everything worked as expected.

So what is `const` supposed to signal?  I'm not sure I feel right putting const where the compiler allows because if I use it in situations like this consumers may not expect inner values to change, and I'm worried about putting on functions that are pure right now but I add side effects later without remembering to remove the `const`.

Answer (score 3):

The `const` protects the members of the `struct B` itself. So you can't *reassign* the pointer stored in `a`, but since that pointer doesn't point to a `const struct A`, you can still mutate the members of the struct it points to.

Answer (score 2):

> So what is `const` supposed to signal?

With `void DoStuff(const struct B* b)`, the data `b` points to should not attempted to be changed.  With `b->a->value = 5;`, the data `b` points to does not change.  `b->a` remains unchanged.

`value` changes, but that is not data pointed to by `a`.

Good compilers warn when code attempts to directly change `const` data.

---

Changing  data that is labeled `const` is OK in select cases.

It would have been OK for code to change `b->a` as with `(struct B*)b->a = 0` as `struct B* b` was originally assigned dot point to non-`const` data.   Had the data `b` points to been `const`, then `(struct B*)b->a = 0` is *undefined behavior* (UB).